# Wait for state data to be complete

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive, MenuTabsComponent:

```
    public $onInit() {
        console.log(this.$state.current.name);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.$state.current.name);
        }, 500);
    }
```

The issue is that this code is executed before all the state data is available. If I run the code without the setTimeout the `$state.name` isn't correct.

> dashboard.tasks.overview.details
>
> dashboard.tasks.overview.details.information

But setTimeout is not a proper solution. How do I wait till the state data is available?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign state.name to variable and use $scope.$watch to detect the change.

```
$scope.name = this.$state.current.name;

$scope.$watch(name, function (newValue, oldValue) {

});
```

you can also check the oldValue to see if it is null and execute your code only when oldValue is null to execute your function once.

```
$scope.$watch(name, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(oldValue == null){
        //execute your function
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hm. It seems `this` is undefined inside the `$watch`. `Cannot read property 'getSelectedTabIndex' of undefined` I'm calling the `getSelectedTabIndex` function inside the `$watch`. Ah it seems you shouldn't use functions inside of a watch. Disappointing.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma you can add a 3rd parameter to your watch function that refers to the current scope. function (newValue, oldValue, scope)